# C++ paths beginning with ~

Tags: c++, path, tilde

Is here any possibility to use paths beginning with "~" in **c++** codes in linux? For example this code is not working correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("~/example.txt");
  myfile << "Text in file .\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a directory in the working directory called `~`? Opening a filed in a directory that doesn't exist won't automatically create a directory for you. E.g. `mkdir \~` .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are on a Linux or POSIX system, with an interactive shell understanding `~` (e.g. `bash`)

Actually, files paths starting with `~` almost never happens (you could create such a directory with `mkdir '~'`in the shell, but that would be perverse). Remember that your shell is [*globbing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) arguments, so *your shell* (not your program!) *is replacing `~` with* e.g. *`/home/martin`* when you type `myprogram ~/example.txt` as a command in your terminal. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). You probably want to use [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) or [wordexp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) inside your C++ program (but you need to do so only if the `"~/example.txt"` string comes from some data - e.g. some configuration file, some user input, etc...)

Sometimes, you might simply use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) to get the home directory (or [getpwuid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) with [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html)). Perhaps you might do

```
std::string home=getenv("HOME");
std::string path= home+"/example.txt";
ofstream myfile(path);
```

If you are serious, you should check that `getenv("HOME")` does not return `NULL`. In practice, that is unlikely to happen.

See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398464/50557).