# how to expand the tilde (~) home in a path with std::filesystem

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

I'm trying to use the `std::filesystem` to expand the tilde (`~`) in a path.

for example:

convert `"~/Desktop"` to `"/homes/thewoz/Desktop"`

know how I can do?

***Update:***

Thank you all for your responses.
Anyway it seems to me that the answer is **NO**.
I was asking if there was a way to do it with `std::filesystem` not a generic way to do it.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544123/c-paths-beginning-with

Comment: just replace "~" with getenv("HOME")

Comment: `~`-expansion is a feature of certain shells. The notion of a "home directory" is not part of either the standard library or the underlying filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

maybe like this:

```cpp
std::string expand_home_dir(const std::string &path)
{
    char *dir = std::getenv("HOME");
    size_t index = 0;
    std::string retval = path;

    if (dir != nullptr) {
        std::string replace(dir);

        while (true) {
            index = retval.find("~", index);
            if (index == std::string::npos) {
                break;
            }

            retval.replace(index, 1, replace);
            index += replace.size();
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

For Windows it's probably a concatenation of `std::getenv("HOMEDRIVE")` and `std::getenv("HOMEPATH")`, I have no way to verify this.

Comment: On windows there is the `%userprofile%` environment variable

Comment: Actually, on Windows, you'll want to be more specific -- there is no single "HOME" because there are several predefined folders for different purposes. On Unix, you generally do something like $HOME/.SomeNameForMyApp/ and use that -- but, on Windows you have a long list of "known folder IDs" that point to various locations. Like, for example, one of my projects stores its data in FOLDERID_LocalAppData -- not in documents, because these aren't files that users actually "open". On Linux, it's just $HOME.